An establishment schema, with a single user owner and many user employees
I have an unchangable user table which stores user data, depending on the role(A 1-M connection with the roles table) the user could be either an establishment worker or an establisment owner. I need to add the establishment, where the establishment could have a single owner but many workers. What's the Ideal solution for this issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Two new tables, Establishments and Workers.
select * 
from establishment ;

+----+--------------+
| id | owner_userid | 
+----+--------------+
|  1 | JJGRANITE    |
+----+--------------+

select * 
from worker ; 

+------------------+----------------+    
| establishment_id | worker_userid  | 
+------------------+----------------+ 
|                1 | FREDFLINTSTONE |
|                1 | BARNEYRUBBLE   |
+------------------+----------------+    

Both owner_userid and worker_userid refer to the unique identifier on your unchangeable User table.

Thank you! Was a bit confused about the Worker table, but then I understood that it was a junction.
